# How do you get motion blur working in SceneKit?

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit

According to WWDC 2017, motionBlurIntensity was added as a property to SCNCamera. I've tried the following and failed to get SceneKit to blur my scene when the camera is moved:

- Set wantsHDR to true
- Add SCNDisableWideGamut as a Boolean with the value of YES in every Info.plist in my Xcode project
- Move a SCNBox by changing its SCNNode's position in front of the camera with motionBlurIntensity set to 1.0
- Move the camera itself by changing its SCNNode's position with motionBlurIntensity set to 1.0
- Animate the camera using an SCNTransaction with motionBlurIntensity set to 1.0 instead of changing its position each frame
- Do the above with motionBlurIntensity set to 500 or greater

I run the following code every rendered frame like so:

```
    camNode.position = SCNVector3Make(cx, cy, cz);
    camNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(rotx, roty, rotz);
    camNode.camera.wantsDepthOfField = enableDOF;
    camNode.camera.wantsHDR = enableHDR;

    camNode.camera.zNear = camNearVal;
    camNode.camera.zFar = camFarVal;
    camNode.camera.focalLength = camFocalLength;

    camNode.camera.usesOrthographicProjection = usingOrthoProjection;
    if(!usingOrthoProjection)
    {
        camNode.camera.projectionTransform = SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4(GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray(projection));
    }
    else
    {
        // Ortho options
        camNode.camera.orthographicScale = orthoScale;
        if(cam_projectionDir == 1)
            camNode.camera.projectionDirection = SCNCameraProjectionDirectionHorizontal;
        else
            camNode.camera.projectionDirection = SCNCameraProjectionDirectionVertical;
    }

    // DOF
    camNode.camera.sensorHeight = dof_sensorHeight;
    camNode.camera.focusDistance = dof_focusDistance;
    camNode.camera.fStop = dof_fStop;
    camNode.camera.apertureBladeCount = dof_apertureBladeCount;
    camNode.camera.focalBlurSampleCount = dof_focalBlurSampleCount;

    // Motion blur
    camNode.camera.motionBlurIntensity = motionBlurIntensity;
```

And here is where the SCNRenderer sets its pointOfView to the camera:

```
    mainRenderer.scene = mainScene;
    mainRenderer.pointOfView = camNode;
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> myCommandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];

    [mainRenderer updateAtTime: currentFrame];
    [mainRenderer renderWithViewport:CGRectMake(0,0,(CGFloat)_viewWidth, (CGFloat)_viewHeight) commandBuffer:myCommandBuffer passDescriptor:_renderPassDescriptor];

    [myCommandBuffer commit];
```

HDR effects like Bloom and SSAO work properly, just not motion blur.
I'm using Xcode Version 10.1 on macOS Mojave.
I ran the Badger sample app and the motion blur in that project works on my computer.
Am I missing something here? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try setting once camera's motionBlurIntensity to 1.0 and not on every frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tested it out, no luck. However, I think I have an idea of what's wrong here. I'm trying to render out one frame at a time. Perhaps the previous frame's data isn't accessible to SceneKit unless it runs continuously? I know the Badger example uses a SCNView to render stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

> The default value of a `motionBlurIntensity` property is `0.0`. It results in no motion blur effect. Higher values (toward a maximum of 1.0) create more pronounced motion blur effects. **Motion blur is not supported when wide-gamut color rendering is enabled**. Wide-gamut rendering is enabled by default on supported devices; to opt out, set the ***SCNDisableWideGamut*** key in your app's Info.plist file.

Test it with my code:

```
let cameraNode1 = SCNNode()
cameraNode1.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode1.camera?.motionBlurIntensity = 3          // MOTION BLUR
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode1)

let move = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "translation")
move.fromValue = NSValue(scnVector3: SCNVector3(x: 7, y: -5, z: 0))
move.toValue = NSValue(scnVector3: SCNVector3(x: 7, y: 5, z: 0))
move.duration = 0.5
move.repeatCount = 20
move.autoreverses = true
move.repeatCount = .infinity

let sphereNode1 = SCNNode()
sphereNode1.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 2)
sphereNode1.addAnimation(move, forKey: "back and forth")
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode1)
```

Works perfectly.